# Can OCaml dune build a project that has a flat directory structure?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

Suppose I want to use dune to build a project that has a flat directory structure:

```
my_project/
├── dune
├── basics.ml
├── basics.mli
├── utils.ml
├── utils.mli
└── main.ml
```

`main.ml` is the main program (the entry point). `main.ml` depends on `utils.ml`, while `utils.ml` in turn depends on `basics.ml`. `main.ml` calls functions in `utils.ml` using prefix `Utils` (e.g. `Utils.example_function x y`).

The question: What should I write in the `dune` file in order to compile this project?

So far, all the dune examples I have seen use this directory structure instead:

```
my_project/
├── dune
├── main.ml
└── mylib
    ├── dune
    ├── basics.ml
    ├── basics.mli
    ├── utils.ml
    └── utils.mli
```

Where `my_project/dune` is:

```
(executable
  (name main)
  (libraries mylib))
```

and `my_project/mylib/dune` is:

```
(library (name mylib))
```

and `main.ml` calls functions in `utils.ml` using prefix `Mylib.Utils` (e.g. `Mylib.Utils.example_function x y`).

I do not want this directory structure; I do not want to create a separate directory for `utils.ml` and `basics.ml`. I want all source files to be in the same directory as `main.ml`. Is there a way to do this using dune?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to list modules of each library/executable for this to work:

```
(executable
  (name main)
  (modules main)
  (libraries mylib))

(library
  (name mylib)
  (modules utils basics))
```

Or you can just put everything in your executable:

```
(executable
  (name main)
  (modules basics main utils)) ; and this line is not needed anymore
```

Comment: Does the order in the `(modules ...)` matter?